# SharePoint list: Conditional required field - Hhow switch off

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

In my SharePoint list there are two columns: A and B (both of them are required).

Scenario: If user will input value in column A, he don't need fill column B.

And reverse, if the user enters the value of B column in column A - he don't need to enter value.

The requirement is important, but how to control it?

Comment: If users adds value in column A, do you want to restrict users from entering value in column B? or it's up to user to keep it empty or add value in column B as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Set **Require that this column contains information** to **No** for both columns from column settings
2. Go to List settings
3. Click **Validation settings**
4. Enter either of below formula (as per your requirement) in **Formula** text box
5. Add meaningful error message in **User Message** text box. This message will be shown to users on list forms
6. Click Save

If you want to restrict user from entering value in 2nd column if 1st column has value, use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([A]), IF(ISBLANK([B]), FALSE, TRUE), IF(ISBLANK([B]), TRUE, FALSE))
```

OR simply use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([A]), IF(ISBLANK([B]), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: I try to use your fomula but sharepoint give me  syntax error.

Comment: Try replacing `, ` in formula by `;` and then use it. Check "Note" in my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, replacing by ; helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to set column as required. Please use below formula in the list validation.

IF([A]="",IF([B]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF([A]<>"",IF([B]="",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))

Comment: I try to use your fomula but sharepoint give me  syntax error.

Comment: You should replace "A" and "B" with your two column names.